# Pgsql - ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x82

Tags: postgresql

I have one query. The query is as below:

```
UPDATE testData SET 
notes = 'All photos saved to property drive: T:\The Station - State College\Quarterly tests\2023\Q2',
updated_by = 81,
updated_on = NOW()
WHERE id = 662927 AND
      cid = 10406
```

After executing the above query, it gives the following error:

```
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.
**ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x82**
```

After removing \2023 query executes properly. Whats wrong with this query? Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The backslash is an escape character in some [string literals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS):

> If the configuration parameter `standard_conforming_strings` is off, then PostgreSQL recognizes backslash escapes in both regular and escape string constants.

> Within an escape string, a backslash character (`\`) begins a C-like *backslash escape* sequence, in which the combination of backslash and following character(s) represent a special byte value […].
> Thus, to include a backslash character, write two backslashes (`\\`).

So you may need to set `standard_conforming_strings` to on, or you should write the string as

```
e'All photos saved to property drive: T:\\The Station - State College\\Quarterly tests\\2023\\Q2'
```